# How to filter day, month or both using CriteriaBuilder Java

Tags: java, criteria-api

someone knows how to create a filter using CriteriaBuilder?

I'm building an api and I need to create a filter for a list method. In SQL Server database, the column is a smalldatetime and the SQL Query that solve my problem is like:

```
SELECT * from TABLE 
where DAY(COLUMN) LIKE 10 AND MONTH(COLUMN) LIKE 5
```

I have a DTO class that I use to filter in my request:

```
public class MyDTOFilter {
    private Integer day;
    private Integer month;
}
```

For example, if a give some day = 5, I would like this response:

"2020-01-05"
"2020-02-05"
"2019-10-05"...

If a give both, like month = 1 and day = 10, I would like this response:

"2020-01-10"
"2019-01-10"
"2018-01-10"...

How can I do this using CriteriaBuilder in Java?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CriteriaBuilder do not have specialized database functions you need to call this functions by name:

```
// DAY(COLUMN) returns an int
criteriaBuilder.function("DAY", Integer.class, "COLUMN")
// or, with JPA metamodel
criteriaBuilder.function("DAY", Integer.class, Entity_.column)
```

The result should be something like this:

```
public List<LocalDate> findDates(int day, int month) {
  CriteriaQuery<LocalDate> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(LocalDate.class);
  Root<Entity> root = query.from(Entity.class);
  query.select(root.get(Entity_.column));
  List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
  ParameterExpression<Integer> dayParameter = null;
  ParameterExpression<Integer> monthParameter = null;
  if (day > 0) {
    dayParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Integer.class);
    predicates.add(
      criteriaBuilder.equal(
        criteriaBuilder.function("DAY", Integer.class, root.get(Entity_.column)),
          dayParameter ));
  }
  if (month > 0) {
    monthParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Integer.class);
    predicates.add(
      criteriaBuilder.equal(
        criteriaBuilder.function("MONTH", Integer.class, root.get(Entity_.column)),
        monthParameter ));
  }
  if (!predicates.isEmpty()) {
    query.where(criteriaBuilder.and(
      predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
  }
  TypedQuery<GregorianCalendar> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
  if (dayParameter != null) {
    typedQuery.setParameter(dayParameter, day);
  }
  if (monthParameter != null) {
    typedQuery.setParameter(monthParameter, month);
  }
  return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: I understand the pont here, I'm using Specification<T> and tried to do your help, but I get another error:

`code
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name
`code`

Here is a gist with the method:
[link](https://gist.github.com/neilprado/4ab656156f743521d607db1b2d9b1822)

My DateFilter class has two attributes:
private Integer day;
private Integer month;

Do you know how to do?

Comment: Commented there @Neil